# Is there any elegant way to build a multi-level dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to build a multi-level dictionary such like:

```
A = { 
    'a': {
        'A': {
            '1': {}, 
            '2': {}, 
        },  
        'B': {
            '1': {}, 
            '2': {}, 
        },  
    },  
    'b': {
        'A': {
            '1': {}, 
            '2': {}, 
        },  
        'B': {
            '1': {}, 
            '2': {}, 
        },  
    },  
}
```

My question is that whether it existed a function that I can build the above diction by:

```
D = function(['a', 'b'], ['A', 'B'], ['1', '2'], {})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This uses the copy function to allow you specify a different leaf node. Otherwise all the leaves will point to the same dictionary.

```
from copy import copy

def multidict(*args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        return copy(args[0])
    out = {}
    for x in args[0]:
        out[x] = multidict(*args[1:])
    return out

print multidict(['a', 'b'], ['A', 'B'], ['1', '2'], {})
```

Answer (score 5):

```
def multi(*args):
    if len(args) > 1:
        return {arg:multi(*args[1:]) for arg in args[0]}
    else:
        return args[0]

multi(['a', 'b'], ['A', 'B'], ['1', '2'], {})
```

returns

```
{'a': {'A': {'1': {}, '2': {}}, 'B': {'1': {}, '2': {}}},
 'b': {'A': {'1': {}, '2': {}}, 'B': {'1': {}, '2': {}}}}
```

**EDIT**: In my solution, the last argument `{}` will be copied into every leaf of the output as a reference to the same dictionary.  If this is a problem (replacing it with an immutable object, such as float, integer or string is a different thing), use the `copy.copy` idea of @matt.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to write using recusion

```
def multi_level_dict(*args):
    x = dict()
    if args:
        for k in args[0]:
            x[k] = multi_level_dict(*args[1:])
    return x
```

your case would be

```
multi_level_dict(["a", "b"], ["A", "B"], ["1", "2"])
```

or even

```
multi_level_dict("ab", "AB", "12")
```

Answer (score 0):

dict comprehension is a cool approach for that, but only if you nesting depth is fixed:

```
{x:{y:{z:{} for z in ['1', '2']} for y in 'AB'} for x in 'ab'}
```

Comment: Assuming fixed depth makes this less useful than the other answers.

Comment: this doesn't make the answer poor, cause I explicitly state when can it be used.

Comment: It's not technically wrong and it's good that you mentioned the assumption, but IMHO this still is inflexible and difficult to maintain. It's also likely that the dictionary in the question is just a minimal example. Would you still do this if the depth is fixed at 12 levels? I don't think that it is "elegant", as the question title requests.